# How to use GPU to speed up computation with tf.Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, gpu

These days, I failed to use GPU to spped up my new program.
My GPU is Nvidia 1080Ti, and I have speeded up my program with the GPU before. (As the GPU-util achieve more than 60%, and the time is much shorter than using CPU). So I think there's no problem with my environment set-up.

Compared with my previous programs that working well with GPU, in the new program I defined a complicated loss function with many tensorflow operations. Since the net model is similar, I think the complicated loss leads to time increase.

My code is listed as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras import backend as K

NT, H_num, Nk = 64, 100000, 64
Input_H = np.load('Input_H10W.npy')
print(Input_H.shape)
input_dim = NT * Nk
Nt = int(NT/2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(input_dim,)) ,
    # tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu') ,
    # tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(Nt, activation='tanh')
])

def channel(y_true, y_pred):
    results, CSI = y_pred, y_true
    a = tf.constant(3.1415926)
    wr = tf.cos(results* a)
    wi = tf.sin(results* a)
    w = tf.complex(wr,wi) #actually W^H 1*16
    mse = 0

    for i in range(Nk):
        hr = tf.slice(CSI, [0, NT*i], [-1, Nt])
        hi = tf.slice(CSI, [0, NT*i+Nt], [-1, Nt])
        h = tf.complex(hr,hi)
        equal_H = K.batch_dot(w, tf.transpose(h))
        euqal_H_conj = equal_H - 2j * tf.cast(tf.imag(equal_H), dtype=tf.complex64)
        snr = euqal_H_conj * equal_H
        snr = tf.cast(snr, dtype=tf.float32)
        mse += 1 / (snr/Nt + 1)
    mse = mse/Nk
    return tf.reduce_mean(mse)


optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
model.compile(optimizer, loss=channel)
print(model.summary())
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./trained.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_weights_only=True)
model.fit(Input_H, Input_H, epochs=2000, batch_size=2048, verbose=2, callbacks=[checkpoint], validation_split=0.2)
model.load_weights('./trained.h5')
```

The result of the program is all right but it runs too slowly. As all thing is normal except the complicated loss function, so I think it is the reason. I monitor the GPU utilization with some software, during the training, it sometimes achieve 30%, but at most time is 0%. And thus my program run very slowly.

So, how can I utilize my GPU to speed my program?
Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: The python console also tell me that the GPU is used (actually, I only download the tensorflow-gpu), however, I think it is not utilized totally.

Comment: Try to use generators with pre fetching, most high end cards like you 1080ti struggle because of the memory bandwidth bottleneck

Comment: I must say another important thing： when the number of samples is only 10000, the net works well and more than 30% GPU is utilized. However, now it is 100000, and 0% GPU is utilized at most time

Comment: I have checked my Memory utilization, it achieves more than 75% (16GB totally), so it may be  the bottleneck?

Comment: Your batch size might be too big, 2048 is really large, set it to a lower value and tune it until you get the best performance.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the GPU utilization increases when I reduce the batch size. However, I still wonder what's the bottleneck? Actually in my previous model, 2048 also works well.

Comment: where your data dimensions the same ? because it how much data and not how many instances of that data. The 75% memory utilisation is a strong indicator that your GPU is starving , and I recommend that you implement a proper pipeline for your data feeding

Comment: thank you for your advice， but Im really new to pipelines， can you explain more detail？ thanks a lot